# Edit Data of Unpickled Objects

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am attempting to use pickle to save a dictionary that includes class instances since json, which I usually use, cannot save class instances. I plan to be able to load them and be able to modify the data I have loaded. Whenever I run a function from the class instances, that would normally change their data, it doesn't. They are readable and can still run their functions, but the data just doesn't change. Below I have put the code for loading the data, with players being a list of the?e class instances, and I put a snippet of code from inside one of the class functions. How do I fix this

```
species = pickle.load(open("species.obj","rb"))
vLanguage = species["lang"]
players = species["instances"]
speciesName = species["species"]

# In separate file imported before pickle data is loaded

def turn(self,env):
  if (randint(0,100)/100) < env.wound:
    self.wound = True
    if log:
      print(f"{self.id} was wounded searching for {action}")
 # If this came out as true,  and self.wound was False, it would stay as False
```